# AWS role update without making changes in the terraform code

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created an AWS RDS resource with the help of the Terraform public module. The main.tf file contains the following

```
module "demo_rds_sg" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-security-group.git?ref=v4.9.0"

  name   = "demo-rds-sg"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  egress_with_cidr_blocks = [
    {
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      protocol    = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }
  ]

  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = [
    {
      .........
    }

module "demo_rds" {
  depends_on = [module.demo_rds_sg]
  source = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds.git?ref=v5.0.1"

  identifier = "${local.prefix}-demo"
  monitoring_interval                   = 60
  monitoring_role_name                  = "${local.prefix}-demo-monitoring-role"
  ........
```

When I try to remove the egress rule (0.0.0.0/0) from the main.tf file I can see the role "enhanced_monitoring" update is listed in the terraform plan. The plan is given below. It is a bit weird as am not making any changes to the role or policy in the TF code. If I add back the rule and execute TF plan again, then it won't list any changes. (expected)

```txt
      ~ resource "aws_iam_role" "enhanced_monitoring" {
          ~ assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
                {
                  - Statement = [
                      - {
                          - Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                          - Effect    = "Allow"
                          - Principal = {
                              - Service = "monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"
                            }
                  }
                      - Sid       = ""
                    },
                ]
              - Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        ) -> (known after apply)
        id                    = "demo-monitoring-role"
        name                  = "demo-monitoring-role"
        tags                  = {
            "Name" = "demo-monitoring-role"
        }
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

  # module.demo_rds.module.db_instance.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.enhanced_monitoring[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "enhanced_monitoring" {
      ~ id         = "demo-monitoring-role-20221219095538103100000006" -> (known after apply)
      ~ policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole" # forces replacement -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }
```

The AWS provider version which I am using is "5.33.0". Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you update AWS provider version recently? and seeing the issue after that.

Comment: Uhm, what is `awsrds_iam_role`? I have never seen something like that. When looking at the module code, there seems to be no correlation between the security group and the role.

Comment: @Marko, that is a typo, it is aws_iam_role

Comment: @Wonderhost and that's the only change in the root module? Nothing else has changed except the ingress SG rule?

Comment: yes, the only change is the removal of egress (not ingress) rule

Comment: The change is occurring because of the code in the declared module. If you inspect the config in the module then it will probably be clearer why this is occurring (but it may require some digging).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MatthewSchuchard could you please share more details like the main.tf file inside the db_instance is the reason? or any other code is causing it?

Comment: `terraform-aws-rds.git?ref=v5.0.1` that is a really old version of that module: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/tags latest is `6.5.2`

Comment: There is nothing in the code: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/blob/v5.0.1/modules/db_instance/main.tf#L145 that explains why the `assume_role_policy` will be updated in-place .. can you provide the entire plan for that resource... seems it ill delete something but you cut the output half way

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I edited my question to include the plan

Comment: That is very strange... are you sure nothing changed manually in that role?

Comment: AWS provider was 4.20.1 and I updated to 5.33.0". No there are no manual changes to the role because if I add back the egress rule, the terraform plan says there are no changes to the infrastructure.